# What is the flat part of an iron called?

Tags: single-word-requests

What's the word for this part of an iron?

[image: This is the part of an iron that I want to know the word for]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [this](http://www.ehow.com/list_6948309_functions-parts-steam-flat-iron.html) it is called the *sole plate*:

> The sole plate, or base, of the iron is flat and roughly triangular in shape. The modern metal of choice for sole plates is aluminum coated with a non-stick material. The sole plate, which is heated and applied to wrinkled clothing, allows a user to concentrate on small areas that need extra attention.

[Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/soleplate) agrees. The Oxford English Dictionary adds that it was first used in 1744.

Comment: I was thinking to a longer word: _the-part-you-should-not-touch_.

Comment: @kiamla: Also known as the *owee-plate*

Comment: @kiamlaluno -- my mom always called it *the-part-you-should-not-touch-* **again** .

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes, it is referred to as the "flat" of the iron (although both "sole plate" and "face" are more common).

Answer (score 1):

I would also understand this as the *face* of the iron.

It's hard to find evidence of whether this is an accepted usage or not, but [a quick Google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22face+of+the+iron%22) does show some instances of the term being applied to this kind of iron.